# How to support external UTIs on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uti

I have been working on this for awhile for an app that I have been working on.  The app is able to open up different files from other apps like mail for example.  I have it working on the iPad but I need it to work on the iPhone as well.  I ran into a problem with testing it on the iPhone, however, because the exported file extensions that I have in the UTExportedTypeDeclarations section in the info.plist file of the app are not able to be touched in mail on the iPhone.

Here is what I have in the UTExportedTypeDeclarations section:

```
       <key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.myapp.ext</string>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>Generic</string>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
            <string>public.content</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>

            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>ext</string>
    </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>

</array>
```

I also have this in this in the corresponding CFBundleDocumentTypes :

```
     <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Generic</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.myapp.ext</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

In conclusion it is not reading the .ext file extension on the iPhone but it is on the iPad.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You might want to check whether another app installed on the iPhone that declares another UTI but claims the same filename extension.

Comment: Hi, I know its bit late but I have a doubt regarding when to use `UTExportedTypeDeclarations`. Will it be used when other app tries to share some data to your app? Or does it have some other function?